# AFRAME mouse auto following

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to make AFRAME cursor to automatically follow the movement?
I readed trough documentation but still didn't find any ideas.

I found this package but this is out-of-date: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-no-click-look-controls

Expected result should be same: https://alexrkass.github.io/aframe-thetarestricted-example/

Answer (score 1):

To "lock" the mouse and move like in an FPS game, you can use the `look-controls` [pointerLockEnabled](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/look-controls.html#properties_pointerlockenabled) property:

```
look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: true"
```

Check it out in [this glitch](https://fast-bronze-flier.glitch.me/)

---

If you want to customize it a bit (like that website with angle limiters), I'd try creating a custom component like this one:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // register component
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      const max_y_angle = 45; // max left right angle
      const max_x_angle = 15; // max up down angle

      document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
        // get the mouse position normalized to <-1,1>
        const x = -(evt.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        const y = -(evt.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 + 1;

        // set the camera entity rotation values
        this.el.camera.el.setAttribute("rotation", {
          x: max_x_angle * x,
          y: max_y_angle * y,
          z: 0
        })
      })
    }
  })
</script>
<a-scene foo>
  <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
  <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
  <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
  <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

---

[Here's](https://glitch.com/%7Egftruj-aframe-react-camera) a glitch with a react example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I tried to do for last 3 days :D

Comment: @kk94kk glad i could help! let me know if anything needs clarifying, otherwise feel free to mark the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I got also stuck with react. Can't get it working with react.

The error im getting is: The component `foo` has been already registered. Check that you are not loading two versions of the same component or two different components of the same name.

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby";
import 'swiper/css';
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import "../assets/css/main.css";
import Img from "gatsby-image";
import { Scene } from "aframe-react";
import "aframe";

const IndexPage = ({data}) => {

  var AFRAME = require('aframe');

  AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
      init: function() {
          const max_y_angle = 45; // max left right angle
          const max_x_angle = 15; // max up down angle

          document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", evt => {
          // get the mouse position normalized to <-1,1>
          const x = -(evt.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
          const y = -(evt.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 + 1;

              this.el.camera.el.setAttribute("rotation", {
                  x: max_x_angle * x,
                  y: max_y_angle * y,
                  z: 0
              })
          })
      }
  });

return (
  <Layout seo={data.strapiHomepage.seo}>
    <div className="full-width loader-view">
      <div className="content-before-start">
      <Img className="logo-image" fluid={data.logo.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        <h1>{data.strapiHomepage.loading_title_homepage}</h1>
        <p>{data.strapiHomepage.loading_description_homepage}</p>
        <div className="button"><Link to="/main">{data.strapiHomepage.start_vr_homepage}</Link></div>
      </div>
      <div className="three-six-zero-image">
      <Scene foo>
        <a-box position="-1 0.5 -3" rotation="0 45 0" color="#4CC3D9"></a-box>
        <a-sphere position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
        <a-cylinder position="1 0.75 -3" radius="0.5" height="1.5" color="#FFC65D"></a-cylinder>
        <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="-90 0 0" width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4"></a-plane>
        <a-entity camera position="0 1.6 0" ></a-entity>
      </Scene>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
  </div>
  </Layout>
);
};
```

Comment: Hey, please open a new Question for your problem instead of using the answer feature underneath another question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53682445/aframe-react-how-to-register-and-use-custom-component

Comment: btw I've added a glitch with a react example